# Getting undefined variable error when passing a PHP variable as a link on an anchor tag on the view

Tags: php, laravel, anchor, href

Am working on a Laravel application whereby I fetch some data from an API (which is an executable link which opens a PDF document when clicked). Am fetching the data storing in a variable then pass to the view but when I add it inside the href attribute of anchor tag I get error of **Undefined variable: quotePdf**.

But when I get the data after dd and paste it in the anchor link tag it works perfectly

**AJAX code rendering the view**

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getquote",
    data: JSON.stringify(allData),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){ 
      //The url that will render the view called quote.blade.php
      window.location.href="showquote" ;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var errors = '';
        for(datos in data.responseJSON){
            errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '\n';
        }
        alert(errors);
    }
});
```

**Controller that fetches the code and shows on the frontend**

```
 public function createQuote(Request $request)
    {

        $quote = $this->global_Curl_Meta(
            $data, 'api/travel/create-quote')->data;

        //dd($quote);

        $quote_data = $quote;

        $quoteholder_name = $form['FirstName'] . ' ' . $form['MiddleName'] . ' ' . $form['LastName'];
        $quoteholder_email = $form['email'];
        $travel_plan = $plan;
        $quoteID = $quote_data->QuotationId;
        $quoteRef = $quote_data->QuoteNumber;

        $data = [
            'sts_quote_number' => $quoteRef
        ];

        //STS PDF Quote
        $quotePdf = $this->global_Curl_Meta(
            $data, 'api/v1/travel/sts-quote-doc')->data;

        //dd($quotePdf);

        //Get all teh variables and return to the view
        $quote_data = view("B2C::travel.quote", compact('quote_data', 'quoteholder_name', 'quoteholder_email', 'travel_plan' ,'phone' , 'quotePdf' ));

        return 'true';
    }
```

**Response on the browser after dd**

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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
```

**The view that is called quote.blade.php being rendered via AJAX, all the variables are being rendered well except quotePdf**

```
@section('content')

@php
//var_dump($quote_data);
$quote_number = $quote_data->QuoteNumber;
$quote_details = $quote_data->Calculation_Quote->Calculation;
@endphp
<div class="container">

<main class="top Quote">
  <h1 class="quote-title">Travel Insurance Quote
    <!-- Go Back --> 
    <a href="#" onclick="goBack()">  
      <span class="back-us"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>Back</span>
    </a> 
    <!--END-->
  </h1>
  <table class="table ref">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6"> {{$quoteholder_name}} </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="highlighted">Description</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="highlighted">Pricing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"> Quote Reference </td>
      <td colspan="2"> {{$quote_number}} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">{{$travel_plan}} Package </td>
      <td colspan="2"> $ {{round($quote_details->TravelBasicPremium,2)}} </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><form>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="highlighted">Total</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="highlighted">$ {{round($quote_details->TravelTotalGrossPremium,2)}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><i class="fas fa-print quote"></i> <a href="{{ $quotePdf }}" target="_blank">Print Quote </a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<h1 class="notice">Important! Please review our policy, terms and conditions before you continue. <a href="#"><span class="noticeClick">CLICK HERE</span></a></h1>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>

</main>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: You mean, its giving error when you use in `href` but if you `dd` in the view file it is printing the value?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Exactly,, thats what its doing..

Comment: are you sure that the view file is having blade template?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Yes it has a blade template,, it has an extension of quote.blade.php

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Seems the issue  is the href tag aint rendering the php variable..

Comment: @Martin Can you show the code how are you returning the view.

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam, I have the same doubt. He is treating the view in some different manner.

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Okay,, let me edit the question..will notify you..

Comment: @Martin My doubt is why r u using `render()`, which will return you the rendered html string. r u returning that string `$quote_data` ? If so remove the `->render()` & try

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Have edited the question,, basically am rendering the view using AJAX..Have also removed render method but the error is still thrown

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Have edited the question,, Please check it

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$quote_data = view("travel.quote", ['quotePdf' => $quotePdf])->render();
```

otherwise used `with` method

```
$quote_data = view("travel.quote")->with('quotePdf',$quotePdf)->render();
```

Comment: Thanks,,, The variable is being fetched and passed to the view,, the issue is when I dd the variable on any place on the view I get the data but when I add it inside **href in anchor tag** I get error of undefined variable..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

`<a href="{!! $quotePdf !!}" target="_blank">Print Quote </a>`

Comment: Tried it but still throws the same error,, have edited the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but this is what I have observed.

```
public function createQuote(Request $request)
            {

                $quote = $this->global_Curl_Meta(
                    $data, 'api/travel/create-quote')->data;

                //dd($quote);

                $quote_data = $quote;

                $quoteholder_name = $form['FirstName'] . ' ' . $form['MiddleName'] . ' ' . $form['LastName'];
                $quoteholder_email = $form['email'];
                $travel_plan = $plan;
                $quoteID = $quote_data->QuotationId;
                $quoteRef = $quote_data->QuoteNumber;

                $data = [
                    'sts_quote_number' => $quoteRef
                ];

                //STS PDF Quote
                $quotePdf = $this->global_Curl_Meta(
                    $data, 'api/v1/travel/sts-quote-doc')->data;

                //dd($quotePdf);

                //Get all teh variables and return to the view
                $quote_data = view("B2C::travel.quote", compact('quote_data', 'quoteholder_name', 'quoteholder_email', 'travel_plan' ,'phone' , 'quotePdf' ));

                return 'true';
            }
```

In your compact function, you are passing 'phone' as an entry which is not defined anywhere and hence it is ignoring each and every entry after that.
Try to remove 'phone' from compact function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning to base64 string ($quotePdf) to view. You can do something like this.

```
$decoded = base64_decode ($quotePdf);

$pdf = fopen ('quote.pdf','w');

fwrite ($pdf,$decoded);

fclose ($pdf);

header("Content-type:application/pdf");

header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='quote.pdf'");

readfile("quote.pdf");
```

This code will decode base64 string and create a pdf file. and downloads the same. If you want return the view you can save the pdf in server and return the file path as a response.

Hope this helps!!